# Проблемы с выводом кавычек из бд

Tags: php, html, mysql

Проблема в том, что не выводит все, что после кавычек (если они попались в тексте).
Я понимаю, что они накладываются друг на друга в подобных случаях (value="$SheetsChanges[0]"), но не понимаю, как это пофиксить.

Вот, как я заношу в базу (заносится в все корректно, с кавычками):

```
<td><input type="text" class="table-field" name="SheetsChanges[]"></td>
$SheetsChanges[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['SheetsChanges'][$i] );
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO in_changes
                (DocumentNumber,Sheet,ChangeChanges,NoticeNumberChanges,DateChanges,SheetsChanges, SelectionDescription)
                VALUES ('$DocumentNumber','$Sheet',NULLIF('$ChangeChanges[$i]',0),'$NoticeNumberChanges[$i]',NULLIF('$DateChanges[$i]',0),'$SheetsChanges[$i]', '$SelectionDescription')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
```

Вот, как вывожу:

```
$sql= "select * from in_changes where DocumentNumber='$CardName' AND Sheet='$Sheet_past' AND SelectionDescription = '$SelectionDescription' order by id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $i=0;
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $ChangeChanges[$i] = $data['ChangeChanges'];
    $NoticeNumberChanges[$i] = $data['NoticeNumberChanges'];
    $DateChanges[$i] = $data['DateChanges'];
    $SheetsChanges[$i] = $data['SheetsChanges'];
    $i++;
    }
<td><input type="text" class="table-field" name="SheetsChanges[]" value="$SheetsChanges[0]"/></td>
```

Comment: Можно пример, что содержат в себе переменные? Какие именно кавычки мешают? Используете ли mysqli_real_escape_string(), когда заносите в БД?

Comment: @Apelsin2020 , Да использую ( $SheetsChanges[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['SheetsChanges'][$i] ); ) Проблема с двойными кавычками, они накладываются друга с кавычками в value="", как я понял. Пример : вфывфыв"вфывыф". Запишет все, что находится до "

Comment: Судя по тому что у вас тут и `php` и `html` сразу, вы показали код обрывками - либо используете его не правильно. И если уж получаете какие то проблемы - всегда есть возможность вывести промежуточную информацию и посмотреть что в переменной!

Comment: Как я понял, проблема вовсе не в кавычках, потому что только что спокойной занёс и вывел: hell`o'a", если использовать mysqli_real_escape_string(), то всё должно работать правильно, но на вопрос подпишусь, если проблема именно в кавычках, то будет интересно почему

Comment: @AndreyMihalev да я выводил переменную, и все выводит верно, проблема именно в кавычках двойных, т.к. они используются при выводе значения (value="")

Comment: Тогда рекомендую собрать все мысли в кучу, посмотреть на вопрос с другой стороны и перефразировать его таким образом чтобы можно было точно подсказать вам в чем проблема. В данный момент я не вижу ни проблему ни причину в вопросе.

Comment: @Apelsin2020 я пробовал даже в ручной в базе экранировать кавычки, то есть писал вместо "О1"      \"О1\". В данной примере мне выводило просто \

Comment: @AndreyMihalev если я буду выводить через одиночные кавычки (value='...'), то мне двойные кавычки выводит корректно, но тогда начинается та же самая проблема с одиночными.

Comment: А попробуйте ради интереса выводить данные вот так: $sql= "SET sql_mode = ''; select * from in_changes where DocumentNumber='$CardName' AND Sheet='$Sheet_past' AND SelectionDescription = '$SelectionDescription' order by id";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конвертировать кавычки в HTML-сущности перед выводом

```
echo '<input value="'.htmlspecialchars($SheetsChanges[0]).'" />';
```

Comment: Я пытался это делать, но тогда у меня выводит следующее: '.htmlspecialchars(

Comment: Может это проблема в том, что я вывожу вот так? <<<HTML

Comment: @findley, именно. в цикле перед выводом <<<HTML, замените `$SheetsChanges[$i] = $data['SheetsChanges'];` на `$SheetsChanges[$i] = htmlspecialchars($data['SheetsChanges']);`

Comment: О, так заработало, спасибо!